# If statement in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, checkbox

I have this statement.
I integrated an "if" statement to validate if a checkbox is checked so i use the value of a datetimepicker or not.

I get the error that an ":" expected.
Does anyone has an idea ?

[image: the statement here (Image)]

Comment: I can hardly read that. Please post your code as code instead of an image.

Comment: Post the code itself next time, not an image of the code!

Comment: Could you copy / paste rather than including an image? The issue is around the ternary operator (? :).

Comment: Really I don't think that linq make you life easier here. Will you be able to explain this logic in three months?

Answer (score 1):

A [ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) requires this format

```
condition ? truepart : falsepart
```

In all of yours you are not providing that falsepart.

(Note I would have happily rewritten your code to work had you have posted it, but I'm not copying it all out from an image!)

In general though, I dont believe you need the ternary operations at all, they could simply be along the lines of

```
...
&& (!someCheckBox.Checked || c.SomeValue == SomeField.Value)
...
```

Comment: thanks.

how do I post code properly ?


And how may i code, that he ignores this parameter if the checker is not checked ?

Comment: @Mote You paste it into the question, and hit the `{}` button with it highlighted - or just indent it by 4 spaces.